# Renjin 'IOException while loading package' on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, renjin

I have a solution that relies on Renjin + Forecast package that works either locally or on a typical EC2 server in Amazon. However, when deploying this same solution on an elastic beanstalk environment I get the following error when initializing the forecast package:

```
private InstanciaRenjin() throws Exception {
        RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
        engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
    engine.eval("rm(list = ls())");
    engine.eval("library(forecast)");
    engine.eval("library(hts)");
    engine.eval("library(rpart)");
}
```

When line `engine.eval("library(forecast)");` is called either locally/on a regular EC2 server the library is loaded and runs perfectly fine. However, on Elastic Beanstalk configured for Java 8 over a 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.5 I get the following error:

```
org.renjin.eval.EvalException: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:forecast: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:tseries: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:quantmod: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:TTR: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:curl: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:224) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryGetNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:182) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:144) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:112) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.Packages.library(Packages.java:39) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$library.doApply(R$primitive$library.java:73) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$library.apply(R$primitive$library.java:34) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.InternalFunction.apply(InternalFunction.java:45) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:198) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:98) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:80) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:51) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:83) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateExpressionVector(Context.java:390) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:280) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:168) ~[renjin-script-engine-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.script.RenjinScriptEngine.eval(RenjinScriptEngine.java:127) ~[renjin-script-engine-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at com.opsfactor.planning.support.utility.InstanciaRenjin.<init>(InstanciaRenjin.java:47) ~[support-0.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.opsfactor.planning.support.utility.InstanciaRenjin.getInstance(InstanciaRenjin.java:32) ~[support-0.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.opsfactor.planning.routines.planning.demand.DemandPlanning.geraDemandPlanDFUAgregado(DemandPlanning.java:45) ~[routines-0.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.opsfactor.planning.services.planning.DemandPlanningService.geraDemandPlanDFUAgregadoComForecast(DemandPlanningService.java:276) ~[services-0.1.0.jar!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar!/:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:tseries: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:quantmod: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:TTR: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:curl: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:224) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryGetNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:182) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:144) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:112) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.Namespace.initImports(Namespace.java:202) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:208) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:quantmod: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:TTR: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:curl: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:224) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryGetNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:182) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:144) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:112) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.Namespace.initImports(Namespace.java:202) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:208) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:TTR: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:curl: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:224) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryGetNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:182) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:144) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:112) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.Namespace.initImports(Namespace.java:202) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:208) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: IOException while loading package org.renjin.cran:curl: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:224) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryGetNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:182) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:144) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:112) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.Namespace.initImports(Namespace.java:202) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:208) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 131 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$file$exists.apply(R$primitive$file$exists.java:46) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.InternalFunction.apply(InternalFunction.java:45) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:198) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:98) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:80) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:51) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:83) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.Comparison.and(Comparison.java:82) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$$amp$amp.doApply(R$primitive$$amp$amp.java:68) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$$amp$amp.apply(R$primitive$$amp$amp.java:29) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.IfFunction.apply(IfFunction.java:34) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:198) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:98) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:80) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:51) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:83) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.tryLoad(NamespaceRegistry.java:214) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 136 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not replicate "file:///var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar" as it does not exist.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileSystem.replicateFile(AbstractFileSystem.java:418) ~[commons-vfs2-2.0.jar!/:2.0]
    at org.renjin.eval.vfs.FastJarFileSystem.<init>(FastJarFileSystem.java:55) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.vfs.FastJarFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(FastJarFileProvider.java:68) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider.createFileSystem(AbstractLayeredFileProvider.java:89) ~[commons-vfs2-2.0.jar!/:2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractLayeredFileProvider.findFile(AbstractLayeredFileProvider.java:63) ~[commons-vfs2-2.0.jar!/:2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:693) ~[commons-vfs2-2.0.jar!/:2.0]
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:649) ~[commons-vfs2-2.0.jar!/:2.0]
    at org.renjin.eval.Session.resolveFile(Session.java:323) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.resolveFile(Context.java:459) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.files.Files.fileExists(Files.java:245) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$file$exists.doApply(R$primitive$file$exists.java:86) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$file$exists.apply(R$primitive$file$exists.java:35) ~[renjin-core-0.9.2692.jar!/:na]
    ... 171 common frames omitted
```

The application is being deployed as a Jar. We have included additional dependencies for the R packages referenced in the error messages (tseries, ttr, quantmod, curl), to no avail:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
            <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>forecast</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-b25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>hts</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5-b5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpart</artifactId>
            <version>4.1-13-b18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>tseries</artifactId>
            <version>0.10-45-b13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>quantmod</artifactId>
            <version>0.4-13-b23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>TTR</artifactId>
            <version>0.23-3-b18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.renjin.cran</groupId>
            <artifactId>curl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7-renjin-b8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FIM RENJIN E PACOTES R -->
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bedatadriven</id>
            <name>bedatadriven public repo</name>
            <url>https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The jar file includes all necessary libraries (renjin and R packages) with the correct versions. What could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Renjin, related to the way package resources are accessed in a sandboxed environment.

I am working on a fix here:

https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/tree/servlet-resources

A release with the fix should be available shortly.